# PouchDB backup & restore in a ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB in a Ionic app and would like to know what is the most efficient way to backup and restore a database. Is there a plugin for doing that?

Answer (score 2):

The only option in plugins I see, that can suit your needs, is this:

[PouchDB Load](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load)

```
var db = new PouchDB('my-awesome-db');
db.load('http://example.com/my-dump-file.txt').then(function () {
  // done loading!
}).catch(function (err) {
  // HTTP error or something like that
});
```

Good luck

P.S. in order to generate dump, use this:
[PouchDB Dump](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-dump-cli)